# Conditional Formatting Based on Column Source

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I was wondering if there is a way to use conditional formatting to highlight a cell value based on which column it gets the information from. I have zone information that is stored in 2 columns (Source A and Source B). The two columns have to be kept separate. I have another column (the one that I'm trying to apply the conditional formatting on), which uses this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",A2 = "UNIDF"),B2,A2)
```

I want to use conditional formatting to highlight any time the information was returned from Source B. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the values of Source A and B distinct from each other?  In other words, can a given zone in the third column always be found in only *one* of the two sources?

Answer (score -1):

Highlight column C (result).  Create a formatting rule under conditional formatting:

```
=OR(A1="",A1="unidf").
```

Comment: Please go into more detail to explain how this works. Otherwise your answer is not useful to someone that needs to tweak it even a little to suit their needs.